# connection refused from host to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a web app within a docker container. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web-app:
    image: org/webapp
    container_name: web-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - ./code/source:/source
    command: tail -f /dev/null

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    container_name: local-postgres9.5
    volumes_from:
      - postgres-data

  postgres-data:
    image: busybox
    container_name: postgres9.5-data
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

When I run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I'm able to connect to the web app from within the container with a curl command. When I try to connect from the host, I get a connection refused error

Comment: Have you checked network filtering is not in your way, e.g. iptables or a router/firewall?

Comment: @apurv, were you able to solve this issue? If yes, how?

Comment: I was trying to connect to localhost. I was able to connect after I found the IP of the docker machine